# cURL ignores CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER

Tags: php, curl, cookies, http-headers

Okay, i have some website which i should parse...
Firstly, i open debugger in Firefox hitting F12, and look at Network tab, then enter needed website, and reading first root GET request, like

```
Doman => website.com
File => /
```

I get there all the request headers and write them into php array manually, then in code i call

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headerArray);
```

and also other options, then call

```
curl_exec();
```

while inspecting the Network tab in Firefox, i see that request headers are maybe such as default, and no specific headers written manually into array were sent. Similar problem with CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE and CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, cookies are just written to cookie file on server, but in fact, there are another cookies in next request instead of previously saved in cookies file.

Actual request headers in browser's inspector:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.1951751996.1563984714; _gid=GA1.1.1564173251.1563984714; _userGUID=0:jyhg490v:AIQdD2Qpm9rmbla1U93mK2a45CFRe49c; jv_enter_ts_2VumZAPpbr=1563984717382; jv_visits_count_2VumZAPpbr=1; .....
Host: localhost
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    $headers = ['Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
                'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
                'Connection: keep-alive',
                'Cookie: visid_incap_1987259....,
                'Host: website.com',
                'TE: Trailers',
                'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
                'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'];

    $curl = curl_init("https://www.website.com/");

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__)."/cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__)."/cookies.txt");

    echo curl_exec($curl);
?>
```

Comment: cURL is server side. What are you expecting to see in the web browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to see the headers send CURL in the Browser Dev Tools. All requests are executed on the server side. Your headers are sent successfully. You can check it out like this:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

$sentHeaders = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
print_r($sentHeaders);
```